# Why doesn't VSCODE let auto-completion happen within the tab stops of a snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I love snippets and use dozens all the time, but am constantly frustrated by the fact I cannot figure out how to make VSCODE guess what I am typing while I am typing inside a tab stop of a snippet.

If my snippet has

```
\\$${1:variable_name}, \\$${2:variable_two}
```

inside it, the tabs work perfectly and put me right inside the text variable where I want to type, but if a variable for example is two lines above this insertion point of the snippet like

$variable_name_here = 'some value.';

when I tab into my snippet and begin typing v..a..r the $variable_name_here never autofills or hints at the fact that it's even listening.

Then I tab out of the snippet and type v..a..r and it immediately guesses that I want "variable_name_here" to go in there.

I am sure it's my settings. I have tried toggling many of the editor snippets settings in the settings.json file and such all with no joy.

THANKS.

Comment: are you manually triggering suggestions? If not, try doing so manually.

Comment: what languages does this happen for?

Answer (score 0):

in settings (Ctrl+,) go to the search bar and type in quick suggestions and then enable them for strings. that will add suggestions inside tab stops. alternatively if you have the same variables you are using all the time you can set up choices in snippets like so,

```
${1|Red,Cyan,Green,Blue,Magenta,Yellow,White|}
```

that will autofill the first option as red similar to if you typed

```
${1:Red}
```

and give you a nice dropdown of all those options.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are not using vscode v1.80+ as the default for the following setting recently changed.

If using a version older than v1.80, disable/uncheck this setting:

```
Editor > Suggest : Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions
```

Then you should get suggestions even within a snippet for words in certain documents, depending on your chosen option for the `Editor: Word Based Suggestion Mode`.